# Ошибка HTTP 403.14 - Forbidden

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Читаю книгу Фримана "ASP.NET MVC5", в 15 главе создается приложение для знакомства с маршрутизацией URL. Код написал точно так, как написано в книге, но при запуске приложения выдает [ошибку](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6XqIlzHy8Q9WW1mbDM4ZDdDNDg/view?usp=sharing).

В чем может быть причина?
Через консоль диспетчера пакетов установил все то, что требовалось для первого проекта в книге:

- Ninject
- Ninject.Web.Common
- Ninject.MVC3
- Moq
- Microsoft.Aspnet.Mvc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте это решение:

```
<system.webServer>
       <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/> 
</system.webServer>
```

Ещё эта проблема часто возникает при "кривом" обновлении IIS или самого MVC. Тогда можно перерегистрировать MVC. Сделать это можно так:

C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319> .\aspnet_regiis.exe -ir C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319> iisreset